# Disable Autocompletion of OptionParser Flags in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'optparse'

options = {}
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on("--language LANGUAGE", ["Ruby", "JavaScript"]) do |language|
    options[:language] = language
  end 
end.parse!

puts "Language: #{options[:language]}"
```

If I run this w/ `./bin/example --language Ru` it will output:

> Language: Ruby

I would like the disable this `autocomplete/closest match` behavior and have OptionParser raise when the exact name is not provided however I do not see a way to do this from their documentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Worth checking the source for a solution here.

Comment: As @tadman indicated, a quick scan of the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/lib/optparse.rb)  looked as if a simple alias of the `complete` method would solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

the search settings are defined in  [`self.regexp`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/lib/optparse.rb#L433)

the method [`complete`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/lib/optparse.rb#L459) seems to return all the different flags.

The method [`self.regexp`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/lib/optparse.rb#L433) defines the search query used

```
class OptionParser
  module Completion
    def self.regexp(key, icase)
      Regexp.new('\A' + Regexp.quote(key).gsub(/\w+\b/, '\&\w*'), icase)
    end
  end
end
```

The regex is built with the following flags

`\A` search from the beginning of the string

`\w*` search any of the matching characters

the [`candidate`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/lib/optparse.rb#L460) iterates using a [method object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html) `&method(:each)` passed as a `proc` with `&`. The `method object` is called on `Completion` class.

```
candidates = candidate(key, icase, pat, &method(:each)).sort_by {|k, v, kn| kn.size}
```

the block `iterates` inside [`self.candidate`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/lib/optparse.rb#L440)

```
def self.candidate(key, icase = false, pat = nil, &block)
  pat ||= Completion.regexp(key, icase)
  candidates = []
  block.call do |k, *v|
    // Search and add candidates
  end
  candidates
end
```

The `iterator` run the following check for `each` entry.
I still don't have 100% understanding of this check, responsible for finding the flags.

```
block.call do |k, *v|
  (if Regexp === k
     kn = ""
     k === key
   else
     kn = defined?(k.id2name) ? k.id2name : k
     pat === kn
   end) or next
  v << k if v.empty?
  candidates << [k, v, kn]
end
candidates
```

Comment: @Kyle Decot [`&method(:each)` is a `method` Object](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/lib/optparse.rb#L440). Still the I don't have 100% understanding of the Regex check inside `block.call()`